# alternative to assigning variable values in while loops?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm currently in the habit of using while loops with my queries to assign values to variables that I use later in code.  Sometimes, this just gets ridiculous because I'm using like an entire handful of while loops to bring together all the variables that I need to put together the desired output from several different tables in my database.
I'm still pretty new to php and am starting to kind of get the hang of pdo, I think.  But, I don't know of a better way of assigning the needed values to my variables than this.  The code below is a very short example of what I'm talking about, just for clarity in case my english is poor.  The code below is garbage, but an example.  I greatly appreciate any suggestions, direction, or insight into this.  Thanks a mil!

```
<?php
$stmt = $core->dbh->prepare("SELECT `user` FROM `buddies` WHERE `id` = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
        $stmt->execute(); $u = ""; $fname = ""; $lname = ""; $burger = "";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $u = $row['user'];
            $stm = $core->dbh->prepare("SELECT fname,lname FROM `users` WHERE id = ?");
            $stm->bindParam(1, $u);
            $stm->execute();
            while ($rot = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $fname = $rot['fname']; $lname = $rot['lname'];
                $st = $core->dbh->prepare("just another query that uses the last values assigned to variables returns")
                                $st->bindParam(1, $variable)
                                $st->execute
                                $burger = $st->fetchColumn();
            }//end of the second while loop of this function
        } //end of while statement 

echo $u." - ".$fname." ".$lname." text: ".$burger;

?>
```

Comment: if your tables where well structured, you could probably get a lot more data in just one query using joins.

Comment: You should be pushing some of that down into the SQL with an outer join and then looping once and creating a single data structure.  The code that you have is not only convoluted but subject to horrible performance issues due to nested n+1 style queries.

Comment: why don't you just JOIN the different queries? your first 2 queries can easily be `SELECT users.fname, users.lname FROM users as users INNER JOIN user as user ON users.id = user.user WHERE user.id = ?`

Answer (score 1):

Use [JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//join.html).

For example, merge your first two queries like

```
   SELECT buddies.user, users.fname, users.lname FROM buddies JOIN users ON buddies.id=users.id
```

You may still have to use variable assignments depending on the scenario. But definitely, you can reduce the number of while loops. If the tables have common fields most likely, you have an association there, and JOIN is the way to go.

Comment: wow, cool!  I'm going to read more about this JOIN thing.  I've actually never heard to it.  Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: +1 for not mindlessly following the question as it was asked, but suggesting the proper way.